When initiating NavigationStack with a path, traversing upwards doesn't trigger onAppear
If I initiate the NavigationStack with a path and traverse upwards with the back button, onAppear doesn't trigger for the views I'm traversing. However, if I manually traverse the same path downwards, navigating back is triggered on every view as expected.

My goal is to track the value of the screen presented outside the NavigationStack. Explanations and alternative tracking solutions are welcome.
Here are my actions and output:

Starting the application with an initial navigation path:

onAppear view: 0

onAppear view: 1

onAppear view: 2

Navigating up to view 0:

(Expected output:

onAppear view: 1

onAppear view: 0)

Output:

...nothing

Navigating down manually:

onAppear view: 1

onAppear view: 2

Navigating up to view 0:

(Now I get the expected output)

onAppear view: 1

onAppear view: 0
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State private var navigationPath: NavigationPath

    init() {
        var startPath = NavigationPath()
        startPath.append(1)
        startPath.append(2)
        self._navigationPath = State(initialValue: startPath)
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navigationPath) {
            Text("View 0")
                .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { number in
                    MyDestinationView(number: number)
                }
                .onAppear {
                    print("onAppear view: 0")
                }
            NavigationLink("Next", value: 1)
        }
    }
}

struct MyDestinationView: View {
    let number: Int
    var body: some View {
        Text("I'm view: \(number)")
            .onAppear {
                print("onAppear view: \(number)")
            }
        NavigationLink("Next", value: number + 1)
    }
}

#Preview {
    SwiftUIView()
}


OnAppear is a little misleading it doesn’t mean that the screen became visible it means that the screen has been prepared to be visible.

Indeed, but does that explain this behavior?

What version and platform is this?

It's on iOS 17.0

If you add .onDisappear { print("onDisappear view: \(number)")} to the two structs, it may help provide some insight as to what's happening. It seems that a view is set as disappeared only when you navigate away from it. And since you never navigated away from the views you appended, they weren't marked as disappeared, although they were considered appeared, based on the initial console output. Strange indeed, curious if anyone has further insight.
